# Объединить в Foreach

Tags: php, foreach, объединение

Доброго дня! Помогите пожалуйста объединить несколько запросов и вывести их в одном Foreach.

Пример:

```
$this->db->where('work !=','yes');
$rg1 = $this->db->get('works');
$r1 = $rg1->result();

$this->db->where('image','blank.jpg');
$rg2 = $this->db->get('photos');
$r2 = $rg2->result();

$html = "";

foreach($r1 as $rw){
  $html .= "<li class='notifications'>
   <a href='".$rw->slug."'>".$rw->title."
     <br>Нет графика
   </a>
  </li>";
}

foreach($r2 as $rp){
  $html .= "<li class='notifications'>
   <a href='".$rp->link."'>".$rp->name."
     <br>Нет фото
   </a>
  </li>";
}
```

В примере выше идет 2 запроса, после 2 вывода (foreach).
Как можно сделать два (и более) запросов к БД, и после объединить их в одном foreach, при этом учитывая что получаемая информация и шаблон вывода может быть разным ($rw->title ** $rp->name и пр.)?

Спасибо

Comment: Насколько я знаю, два запроса к разным таблицам не объединяют в один.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что на практике такие объединения не используются.

Comment: Необходимо просто сделать что-то вроде уведомлений. Но чтобы они в одном foreach были. Так все работает, но не работает сортировка. В данном случае в начале списка отображает все где нет графика, а в конце списка где нет фото. А нужно чередовать, в зависимости от даты

Comment: вам на словах?  делаете примерно такое `select slug, 'Нет графика' text from table1 union   select link  slug, 'Нет картинки' text from table2`   Получаете общий массив, сортируете и выводите